# What OpenSSL v1.1.1g Commands Require A Configuration File?

Tags: openssl

It's my understanding that the OpenSSL v1.1.1g commands `ca` and `req` require sections to be present in an OpenSSL configuration file in order to operate.  Are there any other OpenSSL v1.1.1g commands that require a section to be present in a configuration file in order to operate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick grep through the man pages shows the following:

```
$ zgrep -l "\-config" /usr/share/man/man1/openssl*.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/openssl.1ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/openssl-ca.1ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/openssl-req.1ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/openssl-srp.1ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/openssl-ts.1ssl.gz
```

This means the following commands:

- [openssl](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man1/openssl.html): just mentions the fact that some sub-commands accept a config file
- [ca](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man1/openssl-ca.html): you're already aware of it
- [req](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man1/openssl-req.html): you're already aware of it
- [srp](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man1/openssl-srp.html): `maintain SRP password file`: [see wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Remote_Password_protocol)
- [ts](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man1/openssl-ts.html): `Time Stamping Authority command`: a related PKI utility to obtain timestamped signatures.

Note that they do not necessarily *require* a config file, just that one can be used.

Comment: Thanks, Marc, for the quick reply!  This is exactly what I was looking for.  I have clicked on all of the links you supplied and it appears that only the 'ca', 'req', and 'ts' commands REQUIRE a config file.  Is this correct?

Comment: I believe none of the commands (even `ca` and `req`)  require a config file, you will either be prompted or can enter them through other methods (env variables, or flags like `-subj`). There are just some fields that are tricky to set without one.

Comment: Marc, are you sure that the 'ca' and 'req' commands don't require an OpenSSL configuration file to function?  I seem to recall a comment by @dave_thompson_085 that indicated that both of these commands required a section in the OpenSSL configuration file in order to operate.  My memory could be bad about this, so dave_thompson_085 if I'm wrong please weigh in.